# How do I split a 4 column table to 2 columns on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to split a 4 column table into 2 columns on mobile devices i.e a row would be made up of 2 columns on mobile and not four similar to the screenshot below:

[image: mobile view]
[image: desktop view]

This is what I tried doing:

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Coin</th>
          <th> Code</th>
          <th> Price</th>
          <th> Total Supply</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr> 
          <td> Bitcoin </td>
          <td> BTC </td>
          <td> $ 1234 </td>
          <td> 1203230 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td> Bitcoin </td>
          <td> BTC </td>
          <td> $ 1234 </td>
          <td> 1203230 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }

  thead tr {
    display:none;
  }

  tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  td {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }

  td:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: ' Coin';
  }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: ' Code';
  }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: ' Price';
  }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: ' Total Supply';
  }
```

How do I accomplish the result in the first screenshot? I've searched for solutions and what I tried implementing is based on this [article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) but that didn't work.

Comment: why you should use table in this section I suggest you to use `bootstrap` and col
so you could make your page responsive in all devices
[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)

Comment: It's a challenge bootstrap isn't allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex or grid, flex allows wrapping, grid allow to create a grid.

flex example :

```css
td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: " Coin";
}

td:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: " Code";
}

td:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: " Price";
}

td:nth-of-type(4):before {
  content: " Total Supply";
}
/* media querie commented for démo */
/* @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {*/
  table {
    min-width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid;
  }
   :before {
    display: block;
  }
  thead {
    display: none;
  }
  tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  tr+tr {
    border-top: solid;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: lightgray;
  }
  td {
    min-width: 40%;
    flex: 1;
  }
  td:nth-child(2n) {
    border-left: solid 1px;
  }
  /* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Coin</th>
      <th> Code</th>
      <th> Price</th>
      <th> Total Supply</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bitcoin </td>
      <td> BTC </td>
      <td> $ 1234 </td>
      <td> 1203230 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify this so you can see how easy this is. Basically create both tables and then use media queries to display the one you want.  You should look up the specific media query for the device (iphone6 plus) you want this to work on.

```css
#col2{
     display:none;
 }

  
  
 
  

  
 @media  screen 
  and (max-width: 375px) 
  { 


  
  #col4{
  display:none;
  }
  
  #col2{
     display:table;
     }
  

}
```

```html
<div id='col4'>
<table >      
      <tbody>
        <tr> 
          <td> Bitcoin </td>
          <td> BTC </td>
          <td> $ 1234 </td>
          <td> 1203230 </td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id='col2'>
<table>      
      <tbody>
        <tr> 
          <td> Bitcoin </td>
          <td> BTC </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td> $ 1234 </td>
          <td> 1203230 </td>
         
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```